# where is the error. LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

where is the error here . In the bottom of the code .

*Error  1   Use of unassigned local variable 'Interfaces'*

```
public static void Create_Interfaces()
{
      XDocument Interfaces;
    List<string> intf = new List<string>{"em0","em1","em2"};

    foreach (var i in intf)
    {
        Interfaces = new XDocument(
      new XElement("Interfaces",
        new XElement("Interface",
          new XElement("name", i),
          new XElement("vlan-tagging", XElement.EmptySequence),
          new XElement("unit",
          new XElement("vlan-id", "10"),
          new XElement("family", new XElement("inet", new XElement("address", new XElement("name", "10.10.1.23/24"))))))));
    }
    Interfaces.Save("Interfaces.xml");

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# compiler is not as smart as you are. Even though you know that there will always be something to loop through, the compiler does not.

Because of this, the compiler thinks there is a chance that `intf` is empty in which case `Interfaces` will never be assigned. Since you are trying to call `Save(..);` on `Interfaces` after the loop, the compiler complains.

That being said, it seems like you are reassigning `Interfaces` in every loop, without using the result from the previous iterations(thereby throwing away the previous iterations `XDocuments`). Is this intentional?

Comment: Well it is clear now. I have added  Interfaces = XDocument.Load("Interfaces.xml");  before loop and compiler stop complaining. But there was another question. My xml file saves only last item (here em2).  I'd like to see all three (em0,em1,em2) .Correct me please

Comment: @user3214034 See the last part of my answer. In every iteration you are reassigning `Interfaces` thereby throwing away the result of the previous iteration. Instead of assigning `Interfaces` you should add/append to `Interfaces`.